# PyCharm Docstring :func: and :meth: not working

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide, docstring, pydoc

I am writing a documentation in my project's code but the inline link to a function/method doesn't work. It simply doesn't show up as expected when I use <kbd>CTRL + Q</kbd>:

[image]

EDIT:

Code:

```py
class Editor:

    def picture(self):
        """ The same as :func:`pictures` """
        pass

    def pictures(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Does ``:func:`~.pictures` `` or ``:func:`.pictures` `` work?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to also provide the code as text. This allows others to try the code/solution without having to recreate an example.

Comment: What's the name of your class? If it's `pictures`, maybe it can't figure out which thing by the name of `pictures` you're referring to.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i edited it, sorry I didn't put it before. By the way, none of the suggested snippets work

Comment: @Kevin the name of the class is Editor

Comment: Come to think of it: What makes you think this should work in the first place? The ``:func:`` references are part of Sphinx, not regular ReST.

Comment: But as far as I know Sphinx tags work in PyCharm